# exception when trying to get parameter from URL

Tags: c#, .net, url, exception, parameters

I have a .NET application and i want to get the value of a parameter from the url and then put in as a text in a label of another page.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userLoggedBranch = "";
        string cu="";          
        lbl_CustomerName.Text = Request.Params["cu"].ToString();
```

but the line

```
            lbl_CustomerName.Text = Request.Params["cu"].ToString();
```

is giving me an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
for the moment i don not have the link with the parameter so i am trying to manually put the parameter in the link in this way. If the link normally is 
http://localhost:123/DefaultPage.aspx
i add to the link
http://localhost:123/DefaultPage.aspx?cu=1234 and then continue to open the page if the label that should get the value 1234

Is the problem in my code or in the way i add the parameter to the link?

Comment: try lbl_CustomerName.Text = Request.QueryString["cu"].ToString();

Comment: @EdPlunkett i dont understand how am i calling a method in this 2 lines?   string userLoggedBranch = "";
        string cu="";          
        lbl_CustomerName.Text = Request.Params["cu"].ToString();

Comment: @mbadeveloper already tried with no result

Comment: try lbl_CustomerName.Text = Request.QueryString["cu"].ToString(); and debug it. Try to see if its return values in the "quick watch" option

Comment: @mbadeveloper  in fact now that i see cu comes null. but you have any idea why? isn't this the right way to get an url parameter? should i add something else in my code? Maybe i should add any line of code in the page that i am getting the parameter from? Even though i mentioned before that form the moment i am manualy adding the parameter in the url. Or you think that adding the parameter in this way localhost:123/DefaultPage.aspx?cu=1234 when the url i normaly have is localhost:123/DefaultPage.aspx is not the right way to add it?

Answer (score 0):

Before using `.ToString()` method you need to check is needed parameter exist

```html
if (Request.Params["cu"] != null)
{
   //Your code
}
```

Comment: in fact now that i see cu comes null. but you have any idea why? isn't this the right way to get an url parameter? should i add something else in my code? Maybe i should add any line of code in the page that i am getting the parameter from? Even though i mentioned before that form the moment i am manualy adding the parameter in the url. Or you think that adding the parameter in this way localhost:123/DefaultPage.aspx?cu=1234 when the url i normaly have is localhost:123/DefaultPage.aspx is not the right way to add it?